# IOptions dependency injection in DbContextFactory EF Core

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

Using `EF Core` and Azure SQL. The connection string is in Azure key vault and used `IOptions` to use it in the `DbContext` but the migration is not working now. Hardcoding the connection string makes things work fine.

Have implemented below code due to an issue on migration history table schema. I need to use the connection string in the below class.

```
 public class MyDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<NotificationDbContext>
 {
    public MyDbContextFactory() {}
    private string _connectionString;

    public MyDbContextFactory(IOptions<DbConfiguration> connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString.Value.ConnectionString;
    }

    public NotificationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<NotificationDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_connectionString
            , options => {
                options.MigrationsHistoryTable("EFMigrationHistory", "dbo");
            });

        return new NotificationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
       
}
```

The above code says `"Connection string not initialized"` during `update-database` command run. Can someone help?

**Update:**

Code in Program.cs

```
var client = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
    async (string auth, string res, string scope) =>
    {
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(auth);
        var credential = new ClientCredential(appId, appSecret);
        AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(res, credential);

        if (result == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to get token");

        }

        return result.AccessToken;
    }
    ));
var ConStrValue = await client.GetSecretAsync(builder.Configuration["KeyVaultAd:KeyVaultURL"], builder.Configuration["Connec:ConsStr"]);

builder.Services.Configure<DbConfiguration>(options =>
{
    options.ConnectionString = ConStrValue;
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that u are reading the Azure key correctly and you have the connection string inside?

Comment: Yes because the IOptions has been assigned in the program.cs file correctly and i could see the value being set.

Comment: `IOptions` are usually coming from `IConfiguration` which in turn usually come from various file sources. Please show us your `IOptions<DbConfiguration>` registration in `Program.cs` and list **all** the sources of your configuration if it's used for binding against `IOptions<DbConfiguration>`.

Comment: @Prolog Have updated the question with the code in program.cs file. Please look